# Can not understand a python error

Tags: python

I am dealing with a script which doesn't work.

First i transcribe the error:

```
  File "/home/path", line nº, in out_to_mop_let #~this is the function
    for lindex in range(lstart+ 4,lfinish):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The script is the one below, where i have put ** symbols around the apparent problem:

```
def out_to_mop_let (namefilein, namefileout, keywords=""):
    print namefilein
    filein=open(namefilein, "r")
    fileout=open(namefileout, "w")
    lines = filein.readlines()
    filein.close()

lstart = None
lfinish = None

for lindex in range(0,len(lines)):
    if lindex-4>lstart and lines[lindex]=='\n' and lfinish==None and lstart!=None:
        lfinish=lindex+1
    if "CURRENT VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION" in lines[lindex]:
        lstart=lindex 
print lstart
print lfinish
fileout.write(keywords + "\n\n\n")
**for lindex in range(lstart+ 4,lfinish):
    fileout.write(lines[lindex])**

fileout.close()
filein.close()
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: You initialize `lstart` with `None`. Now if `"CURRENT VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION"` is not in `lines[lindex]` the value will never change.

Comment: If `len(lines) == 0` then you will never enter your loop and never change `lstart` from being `None`

Comment: Looks like `lstart` is still `None` when it gets to the `for loop` and  its trying to use the `+` operator to join `None` type and `int`

Comment: @Matthias right. thank you

Comment: @PeterWood right. thank you

Comment: @CiaranWelsh right. Thank you too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be several potential problems with this script.

1. At the point of the error you describe, it appears that lstart is still
   assigned to the value None and thus it can't be added to the value 4.
2. As noted in comments, the function out_to_mop_let() does not get called, so some of the variables, namely lines does not get assigned any values.
3. The lines variable is critical to your script... both your if statements rely on lines to make decisions.